# Generating war for spring boot application

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, gradle, war

I have been following the tutorial provided by spring and cannot seem to understand why my .war file is empty. Click [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) to see/download the code. The end goal is to download this file, build a .war file and then deploy it to my tomcat server. I've added the following to the build.gradle

apply plugin: "war"

but this only generates a war that contains zero class files.

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle 
plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE")
}
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-spring-boot'
     version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    // tag::actuator[]
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    // end::actuator[]
    // tag::tests[]
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    // end::tests[]
 }
```

Comment: Have you also tried renaming the jar block (with baseName and version) to war?

Comment: Yes but there was no difference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the tutorial code, you need to do two things:

1. war plugin for packaging [spring-boot ref](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-gradle-packaging):

   ```
   apply plugin: 'war'

   war {
       baseName = 'gs-spring-boot'
       version =  '0.1.0'
   }
   ```
2. Create a deployable war file [spring-boot ref](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file):

   ```
   @SpringBootApplication
   public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

       @Override
       protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
           return application.sources(Application.class);
       }
   ```

And also specify the tomcat dependency as provided:

```
dependencies {
    // …
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    // …
}
```

Here is my [commit reference](https://github.com/chenrui333/gs-spring-boot/commit/be88906c7fe66722df5fb34bc8e406a9700268a3) and result:
[image: result]

Comment: Thanks chenrui! I had tried providing it the runtime but i did not know to extend the SpringBootServletInitializer.